# Is the distribution of the maximum of 3D Bessel Bridge same as the distribution of the maximum of 1D Brownian Excursion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Is the distribution of the maximum of 3D Bessel Bridge same as the distribution of the maximum of 1D Brownian Excursion ?

Brownian excursion process: a Brownian motion that is conditioned always be positive when 0<t<1 to 0 at t=1.

three-dimensional Bessel bridge with duration 1: starts from the origin at time t = 0 and return to the origin at time t = 1.

My impression is that the distribution of the maximum of 3D Bessel Bridge is same as the distribution of the maximum of 1D Brownian Excursion, is THIS CORRECT ?

Any intuitive reason for this (or a simple derivation of this) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the intuitive reason, which can be formalized in the same way that Pitman proved his $2M-B$ Theorem (see [1] or [2], Sec. 5.5 page 140).

The 3D Bessel process $\{Z_t\}$ is a Doob $h$-transform of Brownian motion on $[0,\infty)$, with respect to the harmonic function $h(x)=x$ on $(0,\infty)$. Thus $Z_t$ can be interpreted as Brownian motion on $[0,\infty)$, conditioned to stay positive forever. Consider the graph $(t,Z_t)$ of that process and condition it to reach $\{1\}\times [0,\epsilon)$, then let $\epsilon \downarrow0$. Then the conditioned process will   converge both to the Bessel bridge and to a Brownian excursion.

**Edit:** The question asked by the OP was considered by Willians [3] who showed that the Bessel(3) bridge   has the same law as a Brownian excursion  (and not just their maxima). See also the discussion after figure 2 in [4].

[1]  J.W. PITMAN. One-dimensional Brownian motion and the three-dimensional Bessel process. Advances in Appl. Probability. 7, 511–526 (1975).

[2] Mörters, Peter, and Yuval Peres. Brownian motion. Vol. 30. Cambridge University Press, 2010.
https://www.yuval-peres-books.com/brownian-motion/

[3] D. Williams. Decomposing the Brownian path. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 76:871–873, 1970.

[4] Pitman, Jim, and Marc Yor. "The law of the maximum of a Bessel bridge." Electronic Journal of Probability 4 (1999): 1-35.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Does this mean that distribution of 3D Bessel Bridge and 1D Brownian Excursion is the same (for all values) ? not only for  the maximum of 3D Bessel Bridge and the maximum of 1D Brownian Excursion ?

Comment: Yes, indeed the distributions of the 3D Bessel Bridge and 1D Brownian Excursion are the same. That is what the argument above gives, and I now found a reference and added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you again. What is the relation of 2D Bessel Bridge and 1D Brownian Excursion ?

Comment: I don't know such a relation. But the total occupation time of a unit ball by BM in d.2 dimensions, has the same law as the time to first exit the unit ball for BM in d-2 dimensions.

Comment: Yuval: Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Do you know how to accept an answer?